# Most basic ubuntu package

Tags: system-installation

I want to build a Linux system from scratch, and i want the most basic Ubuntu package. If possible only the command line and that's it. What should i download for it?

Comment: Try Ubuntu for server, that should help. If you are doing some mission critical stuff, I would recommend CentOS!

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu flavors](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) gives brief explanation of Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu. You might find what you want there.

If you want a smaller footprint linux you might want [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm).

Do you want a stripped down linux because you think your computer is too slow, or you have limited storage space, or something else?

Comment: I use Linux form scratch guide and just wanted the minimum they require to start